# How was indra worshiped during vedic age?

Tags: worship, indra

How was indra worshiped during vedic age, was he worshiped through yagnas mostly?

Comment: Indra was NOT particularly worshipped because Indra is not one person but it is the the name or title given to the king of heaven. There was for example 1 Vishnu or 1 Shiva but several Indra's over the ages. After the rule of one Indra is over, the title goes to the who ever becomes the next Indra. So you see why it is impossible to worship someone who is not permanent.

Comment: Any vedic reference for this i think this indra being a position comes later puranad